# When generate keyhash value give me some unoknown error in cmd

Tags: java, android, facebook

when i am generate key hash value then give me some unknown error so please help me what to wrong and help me fast
i have already many try but same error give me
also lots of try so please check that and tell me what to wrong
see below screenshot
also lots of try so please check that and tell me what to wrong
see below screenshot
this error give me in cmd
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTqu6.png)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What have you got against punctuation?! 

Comment: when generate keyhash value  for facebook then give me some unknown error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do one thing add the below code inside your on create and check Log you can get your keyhash.

```
 try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.csl.android",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

Comment: If you solved the problem with my answer kindly tick the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is not "some unknown error". You are exporting a certificate by using the `-exportcert` option of `keytool`, but you are not specifying where the output should be written to, and [according to the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html#keytool_option_exportcert), when you don't specify a file to write the certificate to, it will print it on the console - and that's exactly the "garbage data" that you are seeing.

Use the `-file` option to specify a filename to write the certificate to.

```
keytool -exportcert -file certificate.cert -alias todoimage -keystore D:\todo.jks -storepass 111111
```

Comment: then give me new error keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: certificate.cert (Access is denied

Comment: That means you're not allowed to write the file in the directory where you are currently in. Specify a path where you do have rights to write the file in. (You don't want to write the certificate to the `bin` directory of the JDK!).